# Mount ddrescue imaged password protected drive

Tags: macos, data-recovery, truecrypt, hard-drive-recovery, ddrescue

I'm trying to recover a crashed HD from a Macbook.

I've imaged the HD successfully onto my external HD but when I try to mount it I get a `mount_hfs: Invalid argument` error. I'm assuming this is because the drive was password protected (TrueCrypt is what OSX uses, correct?), is there any way to solve this?

Full output:

```
18:14:57: /Volumes/BlackBox  
 → hdiutil attach -nomount -noverify -noautofsck backup_image.iso
/dev/disk4                                              
18:15:12: /Volumes/BlackBox  
 → mount -t hfs -r /dev/disk4 ~/temp/
mount_hfs: Invalid argument
```